# Java 17 JDK & Android Encryption Key Length Restrictions Around the World?

Tags: java, android, cryptography

I am upgrading the encryption used by a Java desktop app and an Android app. Both read and write the same encrypted documents, so file compatibility is required.

Both apps currently use AES in ECB mode, with 128-bit keys. I plan to update both to use AES in CBC mode, with 256-bit keys. Additionally I plan to adopt a better password-to-key generation mechanism.

My concern is the key length. Are there users around the world who cannot conveniently find and download a Java 17 JDK that allows cryptography with AES and 256-bit keys? Do some Android device vendors provide Android versions that don't allow 256-bit keys? My app's Android minSdkVersion is 26.

As I understand it:

- Older versions of the Oracle Java JDK required all users to download and install an "Unlimited Policy addon" in order to use keys longer than 128 bits.
- The Oracle Java 17 JDK does support 256-bit keys, for all users located everywhere. It may be illegal for users to use 256-bit keys in some countries, but the JDK allows them.

Is my understanding 100% correct? I do not want to update both apps, release them, and find out that users in various countries cannot use 256-bit encryption/decryption keys.

https://github.com/EricTerrell/Vault3.Desktop (Desktop app)

https://github.com/EricTerrell/Vault3.Android (Android app)

Comment: If you use a recent Java 8/11/17 version Unlimited Strepth Policy is no longer a topic. BTW the common way nowadays is to ship the application with an integrated JRE version then you as the developer has control over all JRE details.